# Consumer which call method with object state

Tags: java, lambda

I have a class

```
public final class GGGGG {

    private final String str;

    public GGGGG(final String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public void showElement(final String test){
        System.out.println(this.str+test);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GGGGG hello = new GGGGG("hello");
        final Test2 test2 = new Test2(hello::showElement);
        test2.test();
        hello = null;
        test2.test();

    }

    static class Test2{
        private final Consumer<String> consumer;

        Test2(final Consumer<String> consumer) {
            this.consumer = consumer;
        }

        public void test(){
            this.consumer.accept(" world");
        }
    }
}
```

What I don't understand, in class GGGG I have `String str`(state)

I create a consumer with method reference to the method `showElement`
And now this consumer has reference to the `GGGGG` instance.
Does consumer keep a reference to the original object or create a new instance, if it the same reference when it will be garbage collected?

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: Hello world is printed twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java works with [pass-by-value.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40593867/4990642) So,  `test2` and  `hello` are just a reference copy. You still preserve the information where to reference.

> Does consumer keep a reference to the original object?

Yes.

As additional knowledge, the [JLS, Section 15.13.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.3) describes the runtime evaluation of method references.

> *The timing of method reference expression evaluation is more complex than that of lambda expressions (§15.27.4). When a method reference expression has an expression (rather than a type) preceding the :: separator, that subexpression is evaluated immediately. The **result of evaluation is stored until the method of the corresponding functional interface type is invoked; at that point, the result is used as the target reference for the invocation**. This means the expression preceding the :: separator is evaluated only when the program encounters the method reference expression, and is not re-evaluated on subsequent invocations on the functional interface type.*